# Do continuous kth order partial derivatives imply kth order differentiability?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^m$. If the kth derivative $D^{k}f_x$ exists for all $x \in U$ then I know all kth order partial derivatives of the projections of $f$ exist for all $x \in U$.

If $k=1$ then there is a partial converse: if all partial derivatives are continuous in $U$ then the derivative $D^{1}f_x$ exists for all $x \in U$.

Does a similar partial converse exist for higher $k$? More precisely: if all kth order partial derivatives of the projections of $f$ exist for all $x \in U$, **and are continuous in U** then does that guarantee that $D^{k}f_x$ exists for all $x \in U$?

The reason for the question is that I'm trying to find an easy way of seeing a function is smooth. It seems easier to see that all partial derivatives will be continuous then to deal with multilinear functions.

Comment: Odd, as the usual definition of smooth is that all partials of all orders exist and are continuous.

Comment: The definition I've seen of smooth is that all (total) derivatives exists of all orders.

Comment: As I said, odd, as I've taught this material for more than 40 years. At any rate, yes, the two conditions are equivalent, just as $C^1$ implies differentiable. Although differentiable needn't imply $C^1$, existence of the second derivative does imply this. Etc.

Comment: Thanks. So just an induction will do it. I'm just going off the definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Differentiability_classes.

Comment: This should be easy to prove by induction on $k$.

Comment: One problem - the base case for the induction is that if all partial derivatives exist for $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and are continuous then $Df: U \to L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ exists. So then we can't apply the inductive step directly because we're now dealing with a function into $L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$?

Comment: @NateEldredge How would you resolve this issue with the induction? I suppose I could try to replace the idea of partial derivatives with a more general definition applicable to functions into a real finite dimensional normed space.

Comment: It is certainly possible to generalize the notions of derivatives and partial derivatives even for functions which map Banach spaces to Banach spaces (and for convenience you may assume finite-dimensionality everywhere). In this situation, the induction becomes almost immediate. For example, Henri Cartan's textbook on Differential calculus deals with these topics very systematically.

Comment: See also Theorem 8.12.8 of Dieudonne's Foundations of Modern Analysis. Using $C^k$ to mean that the $k$-th total derivative of $f$ is continuous is not so "odd". Cartan and Dieudonne use that definition. Even Rudin uses that definition for $k=1$. It is arguably a more natural generalization of the single-variable definition than is the more common definition (that all $k$-th order partial derivatives are continuous) and it generalizes more naturally to the Banach space setting.